# Unable to convert EST/EDT timezone to another format

Tags: python-3.6, python-datetime

Through Python i'm trying to convert the future date into another format and subtract with current date but it's throwing error.

Python version = Python 3.6.8

```
from datetime import datetime
enddate = 'Thu Jun 02 08:00:00 EDT 2022'
todays = datetime.today()
print ('Tpday =',todays)
Modified_date1 = datetime.strptime(enddate, ' %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
subtract_days= Modified_date1 - todays
print (subtract_days.days)
```

***Output***

```
Today = 2022-02-02 08:06:53.687342

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 106, in trusstore_output
    Modified_date1 = datetime.strptime(enddate1, ' %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data ' Thu Jun 02 08:00:00 EDT 2022' does not match format ' %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

**Linux server date**

```
$ date
Wed Feb  2 08:08:36 CST 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Point 6 in the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) tells that not all Timezone formats are available to be parsed by strptime.

> %Z [...]
> So someone living in Japan may have JST, UTC, and GMT as valid values, but probably not EST. It will raise ValueError for invalid values.

If possible, you could get the server date with the `-u` flag and parse the UTC timestamp.

```
date -u
Mi 2. Feb 14:39:11 UTC 2022
```

PS:
Also watch out for the leading whitespace in your strings.
If EDT is available on your system, the Value Error could be a result of the a mixup between enddate and enddate1.
 `' Thu Jun 02 08:00:00 EDT 2022'` vs. `enddate = 'Thu Jun 02 08:00:00 EDT 2022'`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only a subset of timezones is supported by `strptime`.

If you can ensure that the input does not contain any other timezones than EDT or EST, you could replace these by the corresponding UTC offsets and use `%z` instead of `%Z`:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = "Thu Jun 02 08:00:00 EDT 2022"

date_str = date_str.replace("EDT", "-0400")
date_str = date_str.replace("EST", "-0500")
date_parsed = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")

# 2022-06-02 08:00:00-04:00
print(date_parsed)
```