# datetime module is not working properly on vps

Tags: python, datetime, converters, pytz

my code works properly in local machine:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
def convert_time(timestamp):
      formats = ['%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z',
        '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z',
        '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ']
      for fmt in formats:
        try:
          dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, fmt)
          break
        except ValueError as v:
          print(v)
          pass
      utc_dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
      return str(utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(convert_time("Mon, 04 Dec 2023 06:13:24 EDT"))
```

this code is for converting my date format to UTC format. For Example this format will convert as i expected:

```
"Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EDT"
```

and the output will be:

```
2018-11-01 20:50:27
```

but when i run this code on my `vps` i got this error:

```
time data 'Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EDT' does not match format ...
```

what should i do?
this is what i ran in my local machine
[image: this is what i ran in my local machine]

And this is what i ran in my VPS
[image: And this is what i ran in my VPS]

Comment: Perhaps your VPS has some old and/or buggy version of python or datetime.  It might help to see the complete error.  The strptime command would appear to be raising a different exception since the `except ValueError: pass` isn't ignoring it.

Comment: first check if you use the same version of Python

Comment: @Malcolm My python version is "3.10.12" and datetime version is "5.3".  it will raise this error for each format until the correct format found. It works fine in my local machine. But on VPS it doesn't work correctly and dt is None.

Comment: @furas My python version is "3.10.12"

Comment: would check if string doesn't have extra spaces, tabs at the end. You may also check if it doesn't use UTF-8 chars which looks like space. You could use `for`-loop with `ord(char)` to check code for every char.

Comment: Is 3.10.12 the python version on your local machine, or on the VPS, or both?

Comment: @furas everything is same as before. i ran same version of code. nothing changed even my input test. just copy from my local to vps (T.T)

Comment: @Malcolm on my local machine python version is 3.9.17 but on my vps is 3.10.12

Comment: maybe code is the same but data are different. If you get error for some string then you should check exactly what is in this string - char by char. You could check `ord(chat)` to see if it uses the same codes as local computer, and check if there are extra spaces or tabs which you don't see but for code it makes difference.

Comment: I tested your code with `'Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EDT'` and it raise - I think all problem is because it has `EDT` but you have pattern with `EST`

Comment: [python 3.6 - Unable to convert EST/EDT timezone to another format - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957167/unable-to-convert-est-edt-timezone-to-another-format)

Comment: @furas the first format with `%Z` should parse the date whether it is `EDT` or `EST`.

Comment: I added `print()` in code and `%Z` doesn't parse `EDT`. And it doesn't parse `EST`. But it parses `UTC`

Comment: "i got this error" is really vague. Was it a traceback? Can you post the full traceback? Your code cannot produce that error because you catch `ValueError`. So, where did it come from?

Comment: @tdelaney I added pictures of the result. I hope it can help

Comment: The weekday and month name are *locale dependent*; likely you have a different locale on your VPS.

Comment: You might want to consider using https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html.  That provides a mechanism for handling non-local time zone specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (and the disconnect between the behavior between locally and on the VPS) is that datetime.strptime's `%Z` format only recognizes `GMT`, `UTC`, and the local timezones specified in `time.tzname`.  So if you are in the US Eastern Time timezone, then the datetime.strptime`%Z` will recognize `EDT` and `EST`, but if you are in another timezone, it will not.  For reference see note #6 in this documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail.

Part of the reason for this is that timezone abbreviations are not unique.  For example, `CST` can be China Standard Time or Central Standard Time.  So, a universal parser is not possible.

I would suggest using the dateutil.parser (https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) as it provides a general mechanism for identifying the timezone names you want to be able to handle.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> tzinfos = {'EDT': -4*3600, 'EST': -5*3600}
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EDT", tzinfos=tzinfos)
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 16, 50, 27, tzinfo=tzoffset('EDT', -14400))
>>>
```

Comment: see [Getting timezone from dateutil.parser.parse in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45988363/10197418): you can also define mappings of abbreviation --> IANA db time zone name to get a "real" time zone, not just an offset.

Answer (score 0):

I added `print()` in code and it shows that `%Z` doesn't parse `EDT` nor `EST`.
So you have to add `%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S EDT'`

---

Full code which I used to test it:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_timestamp(timestamp):
    print(timestamp)
    
    formats = ['%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z',
               '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z',
               '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S EST',
               '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ']
               
    for fmt in formats:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, fmt)
            print('     OK:', fmt)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('  error:', fmt)
            pass
            
    utc_dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    
    return str(utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

# --- test ---

examples = [
    "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EDT", 
    "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EST", 
    "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 UTC",
    "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 -0400",  # EDT
    "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 -0500",  # EST
]

for item in examples:
    try:
        convert_timestamp(item)    
    except:
        pass
```

Result:

```
Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EDT
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S EST
  error: %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ
Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 EST
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z
     OK: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S EST
Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 UTC
     OK: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 -0400
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
     OK: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z
Thu, 01 Nov 2018 16:50:27 -0500
  error: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
     OK: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but I added pictures of the result to my question. there is no error in my local machine. I remove the EST part from `formats` an  it works perfectly.

Comment: If your machine is in the US Eastern timezone, `%Z` will parse `EDT` and `EST`.

Comment: @Malcolm I run in Central Europe - so maybe all depends on system settings. But I can't test it.